# Why is my output wrong? C newbie

Tags: c, gcc, gcc-warning

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) 
{
    char username;
    username = '10A';
    printf("%c\n", username);
    return 0;
}
```

I just started learning C, and here is my first problem. Why is this program giving me 2 warnings (multi-character constant, overflow in implicit constant conversion)?

And instead of giving `10A` as output, it is giving just `A`.

Comment: Single quotes are for characters only, not strings. `'10A'` is not a single character.

Comment: I tried double quotes (at first) but that gives me a warning (assignment makes int from pointer without a cast) and gives a output "?" which seems to something with encoding .. am i right?

Comment: How do you expect a single character variable to hold three characters?

Comment: @tadman: Single quotes can be used for multi-character constants. Formally, there's nothing wrong with `'10A'`. Except for OP's expectations that is...

Comment: @AnT Can you also explain why does `A` get printed in this case?

Comment: @Shubham I would assume the multi-character constant is being truncated to fit into the `char`.  I am uncertain as to whether it is undefined behavior.

Comment: @Shubham: Interpretation of multi-character constants is entirely implementation-defined. Typically compilers use the characters as sequential bytes in the resultant `int` value. So, in this case the full value of `'10A'` happens to be something like `0x00313041` (depends on the encoding). When assigned to a single-byte variable `char username` the value gets truncated: all higher-order byes are lost, leaving behind only the least-significant one - `0x41`. Which is `'A'`.

Comment: @AnT Can I also say from this behavior that the target machine could be following little endian architecture because the value `0x41` will be stored in the lower address and the `char` data type will pick this as its capacity is just `1` byte and hence `A` got printed?

Comment: @Shubham: it is moderately likely that you've guessed correctly, but the compiler is required to document what it does (it is implementation-defined, so the implementation must define what it does).  It isn't obliged to do what you suggest, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to stuff multiple characters into a single set of `''`, and into a single `char` variable.  You need `""` for string literals, and you'll need an array of characters to hold a string.  And to print a string, use `%s`.

Putting all of this together, you get:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) 
{
    char username[] = "10A";
    printf("%s\n", username);
    return 0;
}
```

**Footnote**

From Jonathan Leffler in the comments below regarding multi-character constants:

*Note that multi-character constants are a part of C (hence the warning, not an error), but the value of a multi-character constant is implementation defined and hence not portable. It is an integer value; it is larger than fits in a char, so you get that warning. You could have gotten almost anything as the output — 1, A and a null byte could all be plausible.*

Comment: That is the way strings are handled in C.

Comment: @Ahmad Bilal: Strings are arrays in C. No way around it. In this case you can also do `const char *username = "10A";`.

Comment: I saw that construction earlier, can you just explain .. the significance of the star sign, and how is it different from normal ?

Comment: The `*` symbol in this case deals with pointers.  They can be difficult to grasp at first, but are a powerful part of the C language.

Comment: Note that multi-character constants are a part of C (hence the warning, not an error), but the value of a multi-character constant is implementation defined and hence not portable.  It is an integer value; it is larger than fits in a `char`, so you get that warning.  You could have gotten almost anything as the output — `1`, `A` and a null byte could all be plausible.  So, while this answer is 'right for the OP at the moment', it is arguably glossing over an obscure corner of the standard which actually doesn't have much practical use.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I suppose I should add something about multi-character constants as a footnote for posterity.

Comment: You could leave my comment as the footnote if you like.  As I said, you're "right for the OP at the moment".

Comment: Well, while making a login script, I expected C to have similar character assignment methods as PHP/Perl.

Comment: JonathanLeffler, AnT, ChristianGibbons, WeatherVane, tadman Thank you for the help. Though as you would expect, this is only the beginning, and I would be hoping for your valuable inputs in the near future.

Answer (score 1):

`'10A'` is an allowed but obscure way to define a value.

In the case of an `int` variable,

```
int username = '10A';
printf("%x\n", username);
```

will output

```
313041
```

These are pairs of hexadecimal values - each pair is

`0x31` is the `'1'` of your input.

`0x30` is the `'0'` of your input.

`0x41` is the `'A'` of your input.

But a `char` type can't hold this.

Comment: Thank you and it fits with @JonathanLeffler comment.

Answer (score 1):

In C there are no String objects. Instead Strings are arrays of characters (followed by a null character). Other answers have pointed out statically allocating this memory. However I recommend dynamically allocating Strings. Just remember C lacks a garbage memory collector (like there is in java). So remember to free your pointers. Have fun!!

Comment: I would not recommend a general rule of allocating dynamically by default.  With the heap being slower than the stack, I reserve heap allocation for scenarios that call for the advantages of the heap (such as if it will need to be dynamically resized).

Comment: @ChristianGibbons working with malloc will help grasp pointers. Thanks for pointing out the heap was slower than the stack. One follow up question though. Can you run into problems passing statically allocated pointers that are stored on the stack?

Comment: One problem you may have with arrays allocated on the stack is that they turn to garbage when they leave scope (so returning a pointer to a locally scoped array will give garbage to the calling function).  If you need to return the array to the calling function, that would be a case where you might consider allocating on the heap, or you may consider instead having the calling function allocate the array and pass a pointer to it as an argument to the called function.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `char *username` to point to the beginning of the address and loop through the memory after. For instance use `sizeof(username)` to get the size and then loop printf until you have printed the amount of characters in username. However you may end up with major problems if you aren't careful...